# ServiceStack request POST body as query string

Tags: c#, post, request, servicestack, query-string

I am trying to implement an IPN handler in C# and I am using ServiceStack as my backend framework. I am facing the following issue however;

I am trying to find a way to take the POST body of a request as a querystring but I fail to do so. I am using IRequest.GetRawBody(); but the POST data are returned in a formatted way to make it readable.

Is there any way to easily take the POST body as a querystring? I want something similar to PHP's $_POST so I can ecrypt the data with HMAC SHA256 but I can find a way to do it without writing a helper class with hardcoded details about the POST request body. I've tried searching online and ServiceStack's documentation but I did not find anything useful.

Any help will be very appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QueryString is on the URL not the Request Body. If you just want access to the raw Request body that's posted you can have your [Request DTO implement IRequiresRequestStream](http://docs.servicestack.net/serialization-deserialization#reading-in-and-de-serializing-ad-hoc-custom-requests) which tells ServiceStack to skip deserializing the body so you can deserialize it yourself, e.g:

```
public class MyRequest : IRequiresRequestStream
{
    public Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
}
public class MyServices : Service
{
    public object Any(MyRequest request)
    {
        var bytes = request.RequestStream.ReadFully();
        var text = bytes.FromUtf8Bytes();
        ...
    }
}
```